# Getting undefined when using enviroment variables with EXPO and React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, environment-variables

I am using EXPO 49 so According to the documentation I must create a .env file and use this format: `EXPO_PUBLIC_[NAME]=VALUE`  and then I will be able to use env variables in my code with this format: `process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_[NAME]=VALUE`.

The thing is I am getting Undefined and I followed all the steps correctly.

this is my .env file:

```
EXPO_PUBLIC_APIKEY=secretword
```

this is my screen code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
//import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './styles';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from '../../../firebaseConfig';


export default function RegistrationScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')
  
  const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Login')
  }
  
  const onRegisterPress = () => {
    const apiurl = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_APIKEY;
    console.log(apiurl)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The problem was the name of the .env file it was "keys.env", then I renamed it to ".env" and now all work fine.